# Really simple quest - need to test equality of array elements - just not working

Tags: jquery

```
for (index=1; index<=15; index++) {

            if (undefined != sku[index]) {
                //alert(sku[index] + " " + jQuery.inArray(sku[index], mr_sku));
                //var temp = sku[index];
                for (jindex=1; jindex<=15; jindex++) {
                    if ( mr_sku[jindex] != 'null' ){
                        //found = jQuery.inArray( sku[index], mr_sku );
                        if ( sku[index] == mr_sku[jindex] ) {
                            alert( sku[index] + " " + mr_sku[jindex] );
                        }

                    }
                }


            }
    found = -1;
    }
```

I am just trying to throw a an `alert` if `mr_sku[jindex]` equals `sku[index]` and it's driving me batty.

Comment: `!= 'null'` or `!= null`? `mr_sku[jindex]` contains the string `"null"` or the `null` value?

Comment: As a side note, turn this `if (undefined != sku[index]) {` into this `if (sku[index] != undefined) {` You are not validating the value of `undefined`, you are validating the value of `sku[index]`.

Comment: Several items of mr_sku[jindex] has the value of 'null' then not bieng used.

Comment: put the alert before the if and post the result

Comment: Add a `console.log(sku[index]); console.log(mr_sku[jindex])` before the final if to check their values in the debugging tools. `console.log(...)` commands are great in helping you sort out issues like that.

Comment: A fiddle with values and desired result would be helpful because too many things are strange here (for example the start index of 1) so it's hard to tell what's a bug and what's a feature.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl With Yoda conditions what problem do you have? Sorry, resist I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code with dummy data in this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sahil_kapoor/LnjLv/) and it seems to work. My assumption here is that in statement index<=15, 15 is the last index of the array and not the actual length of the array.

**Edit** - Second assumption is that you do not wish to match elements at index 0.(As pointed out in the comment by **dystroy** elements at index 0 wont be matched by your current code)